# Replace bigrams based on their frequency in Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, text, apache-spark

I want to replace all bigrams which their frequency count is greater than a threshold with this pattern `(word1.concat("-").concat(word2))`, and i've tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object replace {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("replace")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.textFile("data/ddd.txt")

    val threshold = 2

    val searchBigram=rdd.map {
      _.split('.').map { substrings =>
        // Trim substrings and then tokenize on spaces
        substrings.trim.split(' ').

          // Remove non-alphanumeric characters and convert to lowercase
          map {
          _.replaceAll( """\W""", "").toLowerCase()
        }.
          sliding(2)

      }.flatMap {
        identity
      }
        .map {
        _.mkString(" ")
      }
        .groupBy {
        identity
      }
        .mapValues {
        _.size
      }
    }.flatMap {
      identity
    }.reduceByKey(_ + _).collect
      .sortBy(-_._2)
      .takeWhile(_._2 >= threshold)
      .map(x=>x._1.split(' '))
      .map(x=>(x(0), x(1))).toVector


    val sample1 = sc.textFile("data/ddd.txt")
    val sample2 = sample1.map(s=> s.split(" ") // split on space
      .sliding(2)                       // take continuous pairs
      .map{ case Array(a, b) => (a, b) }
      .map(elem => if (searchBigram.contains(elem)) (elem._1.concat("-").concat(elem._2)," ") else elem)
      .map{case (e1,e2) => e1}.mkString(" "))
    sample2.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

but this code remove last word of every document and show some errors when i run it on a file contains a lot of documents.

suppose my input file contains these documents :

```
surprise heard thump opened door small seedy man clasping package wrapped.

upgrading system found review spring two thousand issue moody audio mortgage backed.

omg left gotta wrap review order asap . understand issue moody hand delivered dali lama

speak hands wear earplugs lives . listen maintain link long .

buffered lightning two thousand volts cables burned revivification place .

cables volts cables finally able hear auditory issue moody gem long rumored music .
```

and my favorite output is :

```
surprise heard thump opened door small-man clasping package wrapped.

upgrading system found review spring two-thousand issue-moody audio mortgage backed.

omg left gotta wrap review order asap . understand issue-moody hand delivered dali lama

speak hands wear earplugs lives . listen maintain link long small-man .

buffered lightning two-thousand volts-cables burned revivification place .

cables volts-cables finally able hear auditory issue-moody gem long rumored music .
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: " show some errors when i run it on a file contains a lot of documents.". What errors?

Comment: scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@6803a136 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
 at replace$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(replace.scala:74)
 at replace$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(replace.scala:74)

Comment: From what line of your code? Also, that code seems to (sort of) work for me, in that the top bigrams get replaced - but because of your algorithm, the second one of the pair is still in the next entry  of the sliding(2) pairs so "volts cables" becomes "volts-cables cables" in the output. So your approach to substitutions needs to change.

Comment: But it shows some errors for me, and remove last words. Can you help me?

Comment: I think its time you coded and debugged this yourself. Your algorithm is not going to work (because when you get "a b c" in the source, and (a, b) is a bigram you want to substitute, you consider a, b (and substitute that) then b, c (and don't substitute that) so you get "a-b b c"). You can't use sliding(2).

Comment: The match error is probably because you have docs with only one or zero words in

Comment: How can i check a document has only one or zero word ?

Comment: I think this is getting silly. If you wrote the code you're working with here, you surely know enough to answer that. If you didn't write it and don't know enough, you need to do some studying before asking SO. Your code splits each line into an array of words. The length of that array is the number of words, obviously. So check that,.

Comment: @Paul ,If you don't know about my question please don't write comment here.

Comment: Sigh. I gave you the answer. Read my comment again.

Comment: but this problem "a-b b c"  unresolved yet, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: You have to step through word by word building up the output. Take the most recent word added, and the next one. Look that pair up in the top-n list of bigrams. If it's there, replace the most recent with the pair-with-dash. If not there, just add the next word to the output and move on to the next word. A foldLeft would do it.

Comment: Or do what @ayanguha's answer does - make a string from each top-n bigram and replace any occurrences in the string with the "firstword-secondword" form.

Comment: Can you give me a clear answer or code ? because i am confused .

Comment: I think it's time for you to put some effort in rather than expecting others to provide the code. Try writing something yourself, and post specific questions when you get stuck.

Comment: @Paul, I think it is a specific question.

Comment: The specific question is "give me the code". That;'s not the way SO works. Put some effort in. Or explain why it's unclear and what you are confused about and someone might respond. It's more likely if you've demonstrated you've put some work into this too, though.

Comment: Well , at first, you tell me "i don't know"

Comment: Is this question still open? I see two valid answers below, but no acceptance. Would be nice to accept the answer that fulfilled your question - quite some effort has been spent here. /cc @paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getNgrams(sentence):
    out = []
    sen = sentence.split(" ")
    for k in range(len(sen)-1):
        out.append((sen[k],sen[k+1]))
    return out    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        lsc = LocalSparkContext.LocalSparkContext("Recommendation","spark://BigData:7077")
        sc = lsc.getBaseContext()
        ssc = lsc.getSQLContext()
        inFile = "bigramstxt.txt"
        sen = sc.textFile(inFile,1)
        v = 1
        brv = sc.broadcast(v)
        wordgroups = sen.flatMap(getNgrams).map(lambda t: (t,1)).reduceByKey(add).filter(lambda t: t[1]>brv.value)
        bigrams = wordgroups.collect()
        sc.stop()
        inp = open(inFile,'r').read()
        print inp
        for b in bigrams:
            print b
            inp = inp.replace(" ".join(b[0]),"-".join(b[0]))

        print inp

    except:
        raise
        sc.stop()
```

Comment: Would be +1, but -1 for python not the OP's language cancels that out.

Answer (score 3):

Spoonfeeding:

```
 case class Bigram(first: String, second: String) {

 def mkReplacement(s:String) = s.replaceAll(first + " " + second, first + "-" + second)
  }

 val data = List(
"surprise heard thump opened door small seedy man clasping package wrapped",
"upgrading system found review spring two thousand issue moody audio mortgage backed",
"omg left gotta wrap review order asap",
"understand issue moody hand delivered dali lama",
"speak hands wear earplugs lives . listen maintain link long",
"buffered lightning two thousand volts cables burned revivification place",
"cables volts cables finally able hear auditory issue moody gem long rumored music")

def stringToBigrams(s: String) = {
    val words = s.split(" ")
    if (words.size >= 2) {
      words.sliding(2).map(a => Bigram(a(0), a(1)))
    } else
      Iterator[Bigram]()
  }

val bigrams = data.flatMap { stringToBigrams }
//use reduceByKey rather than groupBy for Spark
val bigramCounts = bigrams.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)

val threshold = 2
val topBigrams = bigramCounts.collect{case (b, c) if c >= threshold => b}

val replaced = data.map(r => 
      topBigrams.foldLeft(r)((r, b) => b.mkReplacement(r)))

replaced.foreach(println)
//> surprise heard thump opened door small seedy man clasping package wrapped
//| upgrading system found review spring two-thousand issue-moody audio mortgage backed
//| omg left gotta wrap review order asap
//| understand issue-moody hand delivered dali lama
//| speak hands wear earplugs lives . listen maintain link long
//| buffered lightning two-thousand volts-cables burned revivification place
//| cables volts-cables finally able hear auditory issue-moody gem long rumored music
```