# OutOfMemoryError in Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I used this code for extracting bigrams from a text file:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
object DS_E6 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    case class Bigram(first: String, second: String) {
      def mkReplacement(s: String) = s.replaceAll(first + " " + second, first + "-" + second)
    }

    def stringToBigrams(s: String) = {
      val words = s.split(" ")
      if (words.size >= 2) {
        words.sliding(2).map(a => Bigram(a(0), a(1)))
      } else
        Iterator[Bigram]()
    }

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("bigram")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val data = sc.textFile("data/file.txt")
      val bigrams = data.flatMap {
        stringToBigrams
      }.collect()

      val bigramCounts = bigrams.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
      val threshold = 100
      val topBigrams = bigramCounts.filter(_._2 >= threshold).map(_._1)
      topBigrams.foreach(println)
      val replaced = data.map(r => topBigrams.foldLeft(r)((r, b) => b.mkReplacement(r)))
      val replaced1 = replaced.zipWithIndex()
        .map { case (line, i) => i.toString + "," + line}

      replaced1.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("data/output.txt")
    }
  }
}
```

my input file is 45 MB ,
when i run this code it shows me below error:
(i think it is related to Collect())

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

at org.spark-project.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:342)
at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:526)
at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$600(QueuedThreadPool.java:44)
at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: When running your app try increasing JVM heap size, e.g. -Xmx1G

Comment: How can i set JVM heap size to -Xmx1G ?

Comment: How do you run the code you provided?

Comment: BTW, if the code you provided is all you need to do you don't need to use Spark at all. A simple Python script or Scala application will be faster and will use less memory.

Comment: maybe my input file be more than 2GB , then Python and Scala scripts are more faster?

Comment: i run it in IntellijIDEA on Mac OS

Comment: 2GB can easily fit in memory of any modern laptop. It is also much easier to make a python script faster than to make Spark app faster. Unfortunately I don't use Intellj so cannot tell the exact place to specify JVM heap size. You should open the dialog that you use to run the app and search for option JVM options or something similar and put -Xmx1G there.

Comment: @kostya, the code the OP "provided" was mostly written by me and not the OP. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30681833/21755

Comment: yes it's probably the collect. That's forcing the bigrams RDD back to an ordinary collection, and it won't fit. You don't need to do that, you can continue to work with RDDs. Or as @kostya says, just do it without Spark at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you are not actually getting the 1g of memory that you are requesting via SparkConf.  The reason is that when `master = local`, Spark driver and executor will be entirely running inside the JVM that is running your code shown here that creates the SparkContext.  By that time, it's too late to obtain more Java heap than was allocated when the JVM started.  You need to add that `-Xmx1G` arg to the command IntelliJ uses to launch the JVM that runs your code.

You don't say exactly how you're running your code in IntelliJ. But what you'll need to do is to create or modify a "Run Configuration".

In the IntelliJ UI, under the "Run" toolbar menu, select the command "Edit Configurations...". That will bring up a window such as is shown below. This shows my Run Configuration for running in the "Scala Console". The box for "VM options:" is where you need to include the `-Xmx1G` jvm arg. In my case, I am running with 2.5G of memory.

IntelliJ might already have created a Run Configuration for you when you previously ran your app. If not, use this window to create a new one of the proper type, e.g. "Scala Console".

To check memory in a running Scala app, use the following commands to check your actual current, max, and free jvm memory to see if you actually got the memory you requested.

- sys.runtime.totalMemory()
- sys.runtime.maxMemory()
- sys.runtime.freeMemory()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your application try to increase the spark.driver.memory (is 512mb by default) by setting the parameter :

```
--driver-memory 4g
```

Check the spark documentation for more information about this kind of parameters : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html