# How to extract bigrams and trigrams in Scala?

Tags: scala, n-gram

Suppose these are my documents:

```
very pleased product . phone lightweight comfortable sound quality good house yard . 
quality construction phone base unit good . ample supply cable adapter . plug computer soundcard .
shop unit mail rebate . unit battery pack hold play time strap carr headphone adapter cable perfect digital copy optical. component micro plug stereo connector cable micro plug rca cable . 
unit primarily record guitar jam session . input plug provide power plug microphone . decent stereo mic need digital recording performance . mono mode double recording time .
admit like new electronic toy . digital camera not impress .
```

and I want to extract all bigrams and trigrams with their occurrence number from each sentence, in every document.

and I've tried:

```
case class trigram(first: String, second: String,third: String) {
  def mkReplacement(s: String) = s.replaceAll(first + " " + second + " " + third, first + "-" + second + "-" + third)
}

def stringToTrigrams(s: String) = {
  val words = s.split(".")
  if (words.size >= 3) {
    words.sliding(3).map(a => tigram(a(0),a(1),a(2)))
  }
  else
    Iterator[tigram]()
}

val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val data = sc.textFile("docs")

val trigrams = data.flatMap {
  stringToTrigrams
}.collect()

val trigramCounts = trigrams.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

but it doesn't show any trigram?

Comment: While it's nice to see my code re-used, an acknowledgement would be nice (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30681833/21755)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 def stringToTrigrams(s: String) = {
  val words = s.split(".")
  if (words.size >= 3) {
    words.sliding(3).map(a => trigram(a(0),a(1),a(2)))
  } else Iterator[trigram]()
}
```

IIUC, this function is taking the whole document above and then splitting the document on ".".  This is your first problem.  Calling split(".") doesn't do what you think it does.  You are actually splitting on a wildcard character instead of on "." like you want.  Change this to "\." and you will split the document into sentences.

Once that is done, we need to split the sentences into words by simply splitting on whitespace which I recommend by doing `_.split(\\s+)` which will split on all whitespace.  Now you should be able to parse through the words and create trigrams using a function like this:

```
def stringToTrigrams(s: String) = {
  val sentences = s.split("\\.")
  sentences flatMap { sent => 
    val words = sent.split("\\s+").filter(_ != "")
    if (words.length >= 3)
      words.sliding(3).map(a => trigram(a(0), a(1), a(2))
    else Iterator[trigram]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.